How To Send A Request to Google Routes API on the Client Side
On 1 March 2025, support for Google Directions API will be discontinued in favour of Routes API.
Currently, on all my projects, requests for Routes on Google Directions API are made on the client side using DirectionsService() and DirectionsRenderer(): the user inputs their address, this makes a request to Directions API which then returns a route on the map, detailing their journey to the destination.
The ultimate goal is to re-create what Directions API is doing currently - so that users can input their route onto the map and then get the route displayed on it using the newer Routes API
The projects are old, they use just Javascript and Jquery.
On the Routes API documentation - it is stated that a POST request needs to be made using cURL on the server side.
Is it possible to make a request to Routes API on the client side, if so how do you go about doing this?
N.B.
Many will be having the same problem before the migration on March 1 2025, so please consider this before downvoting or closing the question as this will be useful for people having to make the migration themselves and who have little understanding of cURL/Google Maps API etc.
Thanks in advance

Where does it say the Directions Service in the JavaScript API is being discontinued?

It was sent out via email to users: https://github.com/home-assistant/core/issues/132894

That talks about the (server-side) Directions Matrix API, not the (client-side) Google Maps JavaScript API v3

But you will still have to make changes to the client-side code because of these changes from Directions Matrix to Routes API as listed below, right? Or am I not understanding that correctly?
